# compare two Json objects by a common key values - java approach

Tags: java, json

String json1 =

```
"[
  {
    "title": "Title1",
     "newFiled": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Title2",
     "newFiled": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Title33",
     "newFiled": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Title44",
     "newFiled": 9
  }
]"
```

String json2 =

```
"[
  {
    "title": "Title1",
     "filed1": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Title2",
     "filed 1": 3
  }
]"
```

what I wanted is to compare two json objects by title and merge the equal blocks. for an example I need the out as below.

```
[
  {
    "title": "Title1",
     "filed1": 5,
     "newFiled": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Title2",
    "filed 1": 3,
    "newFiled": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Title33",
     "newFiled": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Title44",
     "newFiled": 9
  }
]
```

can anyone suggest a java approach . Thank you.

I've tried below codes so far.

```
String JSONBody2 = new Gson().toJson(merge(json1Obj, json2Obj));
        System.out.println("######## : " + JSONBody2);

JSONCompareResult result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(json3, json5, JSONCompareMode.STRICT);
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@ : " + result.toString());
```

Comment: Can you show some java code, that what you have tried so far?

Comment: i've tried 

Gson g = new Gson();
        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, Object> firstMap = g.fromJson(json3, mapType);
        Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(json5, mapType);
        System.out.println("************* : "+Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap));

Comment: 2nd try

 JSONArray sourceArray = new JSONArray(s2);
        JSONArray destinationArray = new JSONArray(s1);

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length(); i++) {
            destinationArray.put(sourceArray.getJSONObject(i));
        }

        System.out.println("@@@@@#######@@@ : " +destinationArray.toString());

Comment: Please put your code in your question, not in comments!

Comment: @nobalG above 4 tried by myself but no luck as expected in the question.

Comment: @tgdavies added. but two approaches couldn't add to question it self due to an error.so  added to comment section.

Comment: any expert answers pls ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Brute-Force solution I wrote which takes `O(n * s)` runtime. See if it solves your use case? and maybe try to improve it and optimize it (you can optimize it to `O(n + s)`).

The solution considers all maps pairs of the two lists that have key `title` with the same values.

```java
public static String mergeJsonByKeyValues(String json1, String json2, String key) throws JsonProcessingException {
    if (key == null) key = "title";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> data1 = objectMapper.readValue(json1, List.class);
    List<HashMap<String, String>> data2 = objectMapper.readValue(json2, List.class);
    int n = data1.size() > data2.size() ? data1.size() : data2.size();
    int s = data1.size() + data2.size() - n;

    List<HashMap<String, String>> mergedJson = new ArrayList<>(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> data1Item = data1.size() == n ?
                new HashMap<>(data1.get(i)) : new HashMap<>(data2.get(i));
        if (!data1Item.containsKey(key)) continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++) {
            HashMap<String, String> data2Item = data2.size() == s ? data2.get(j) : data1.get(j);
            if (!data2Item.containsKey(key)) continue;

            if (data1Item.get(key).equals(data2Item.get(key))) {
                data1Item.putAll(data2Item);
                mergedJson.add(data1Item);
            }
        }

        if (i >= s) mergedJson.add(data1Item);
    }
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mergedJson);
}
```

Test on your json examples:

```java
String json1 = "[{ \"title\": \"Title1\", \"newFiled\": 5 }," +
        "{ \"title\": \"Title2\", \"newFiled\": 3 }," +
        "{ \"title\": \"Title33\", \"newFiled\": 10 }," +
        "{ \"title\": \"Title44\", \"newFiled\": 9 }]";
String json2 = "[{ \"title\": \"Title1\", \"filed1\": 5 }," +
        "{ \"title\": \"Title2\", \"filed 1\": 3 }]";
String key = "title";

System.out.println(mergeJsonByKeyValues(json1, json2, key));
// [{"title":"Title1","newFiled":5,"filed1":5},{"title":"Title2","newFiled":3,"filed 1":3},{"title":"Title33","newFiled":10},{"title":"Title44","newFiled":9}]
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch. I was able to find a solution bit similar to you one, But again Thanks a lot.